# How to transform a non linear response variable to linear variable in R

Tags: r, transform

I am trying to transform the response variable Hb to be linear before fitting my linear mixed effect model

[image]

I firstly tried by using filter function in dplyr and this is what I get
[image]

can any one assist? the filter didnt seem to work. heres my code

```js
malariadata_Longnew <- malariadata_Long %>% 
  arrange(pid) %>%
  mutate(pday = as.numeric(pday))  %>% 
  filter(Hb >= 7 & Hb >= 11) 
  
 malariadata_Longfinal <- groupedData(logHb~arm|pid/site, data = malariadata_Longnew, outer =~gender)
malariadata_Longfinal

str(malariadata_Longfinal)
plot(malariadata_Longfinal,aspect = 2) ###Hb profile has non liner shape
```

Comment: I think another log transform should do it

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk thanks for the response. I tried doing a log transform (log1p). However, it still has a small non-lear dip at the top.

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear I meant to say that you should try a log(log) transform

Comment: that's because your logHb looks like an exponential function A exp(-lambda*t)